# Morag Tong set boost poison applied to weapon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The 5th item text for the Morag Tong set reads that enemies “...take 10% more damage from all Poison Damage abilities...”

Notice the word “abilities”. I’m worried that this set will **not** boost damage from alchemical poison applied to a weapon. Does it or not?

Has anyone tested this or has Zenimax answered such a question on their forums?

A strictly technical reading would suggest that it does not boost alchemical poison applied to weapons, but we all know about editing mistakes or outdated descriptions and the challenge of fully describing complex logic in concise blurbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/elderscrollsonline/comments/7bte8x/discussion_morag_tong_set/), it works for all poison damage:

> [The Morag Tong set] applies a debuff on the target that just makes them take more
>   poison damage.
>   **So it works for set procs and enchants too**.

Comment: First, thanks for that thread. I’m also accepting your answer, because the logic of poison debuff on target would include alchemical poison, but notice how it doesn’t mention alchemical poison just enchantments and set procs. And there is another thread doubting alchemical poison is included and no one answers. Ah, well.

Comment: I noticed that, yes. I found a few other threads mentioning the Morag Tong set, and, although in one other thread the same reluctance is mentioned, at least nowhere there is explicit mention of the debuff not applying to alchemical poison.